# Web page size too wide

Tags: html, css

my homepage appears to be wider than necessary and I cant understand why -

[HomePage](https://ibb.co/hYtFYqN)

While my about page is just normal size --

[About Page](https://ibb.co/HY1C9Pq)

What could be the culprit ?

Also, my header appears to be overlapping with the body in the about page, can anyone suggest some ideas as to why? I need to make it appear pretty much the same as the HomePage. Thank you!

Index html and CSS

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home | Lobo Academy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">

</head>





<body>

    <!------ Navigation -------> 
    
<header>
    <div class="header">
   
    <div class="top-div">
        <div class="top-div-left"> Get a free bjj class NOW 
                                    Call us at 456465464</div>
       

                                    

    </div>


    <div>
    <nav><ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        <img id="logo" src="logo_header.webp">
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="Store.html">Store</a></li>


    </ul>

    </div>    </nav>

        
</header></div>




<main>
        


        <!----- Top Section - Triple Image ------->


        <!---- Welcome Video ------>
    <div class="welcome-video">
            <video id="welcome-video-id" src="welcome_banner_video.mp4" height="500px" width="100%" autoplay muted></video>


    </div>




        <button class="top-button">New to Martial Arts? Click here</button>


<div class="welcome-text">
    <p><h1>Welcome!</h1>
    <main>We are the premiere Brazilian Jiu Jitsu training center in the Charlotte metro area. Head instructor, Lucas Lepri, is among the most decorated jiu jitsu athletes in the entire world, and we are part of the most dominant team in the history of the sport, Alliance.

        We believe jiu jitsu is more than just a sport, self-defense system, or fitness program; it’s a lifestyle that improves the whole person. The physical, mental, and transcendent benefits of jiu jitsu should be accessible to everyone, from beginner to world-class competitor and any age, sex, or ethnicity.
        
        We will help you achieve your goals, whether it is self defense, weight loss, confidence or to be a world champion. In the process, you will transform your life and become tougher, safer, fitter, & better.</main></p>
</div>


<div class="welcome-programs"><h2 id="prog-text">Programs and Classes</h2></div>

        <section class="top-section">



            <div class="left-wrap">
                <div class= "left-wrap-inner">
                    <div class="top_left" ><img src="kids_left_banner.jpg" ></div> 
                    <div class="top-left-text">
                        <h2 id="kids-martial-arts">Kids Martial Arts</h2>
                        <p>Learning a martial art, and Brazilian jiu jitsu in particular, is one of the best gifts you­ can provide a child. It provides character development and personal growth.
                      <br>  Click to learn more.</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class ="center-wrap">
                <div class="center-wrap-inner">
                    <div class="top_center" ><img src="trainer1.jpg"></div>
                    <div class="top-center-text">
                        <h2>Brazilian Jiu Jitsu</h2>
                        <p>Brazilian Jiu Jitsu is a sport, self-defense system, and a fitness program. It has proven to be the most practical and effective self-defense system in the world.</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div class="right-wrap">
                <div class="right-wrap-inner">
                    <div class="top_right"><img src="center.jpg" ></div>
                    <div class="top-right-text">
                        <h2>Weight Loss</h2>
                        <p>If you are looking to learn Brazilian Jiu Jitsu with maximum efficiency, private lessons will help reduce the amount of time it takes to reach key milestones.</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>


            

        </section>

        <!--------- End of Top section --------->





        <!---------- Middle Section : Kids ---------->


        <div class="mid-sec-header"><h2 id="coach-info">Alan Surmont</h2></div>
        <section class="mid-section">
            <div class="mid-wrap">
                <div class="mid-section-inner-left">
                    <div class="kids-img"><img src="trainer1.jpg"></div>
                
                </div>

                <div class="mid-section-inner-right">
                    <div class="text-mid">
                        <button class="kid-button">Get a <strong>FREE</strong> Brazilian Jiu Jitsu Class here</button>
                        <p>Alan Surmont is the leading Israeli BJJ Champion, trained by his father Pascal Surmont, the former
                            Belgian Judo Sensei for over 9 years                <br>
                                            <br>
                            
                            
                            Currently training under Moshe Rubinov and is a brown belt under the Marcelo Garcia Association</p>
                    </div>
            
                
            </div>

            </div>
        
        </section>

        <!----------- End of Middle Section --------->




        <!---------- Youtube testimonials -------->


        <section class="lower-section-youtube">


           
        <div class="vids">
            <div class="youtube-left">
            <h1 id="adult-testemonial">Adult class Testemonial</h1>
            <iframe width="600" height="470" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/vTFFUcppZSY" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        
            </div>

            <div class="youtube-right">
                <h1 id="children-testemonial">Children Class Testemonial</h1>
                <iframe width="600" height="600" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qmu47bjwyCw?start=30" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>

        </div>

        </section>

            <!----------------- End of Youtube testimonials ------>


            <!---------- Recent news section -------->
        
        <section>


        <div class="recent-posts">


            <div class="recent-right"><a href=""><h1>New Location</h1>
                <p>Our Lepri BJJ affiliated academy in Winston-Salem is now in a new location since January 2020. They are now at located at 1606 South Stratford Road, suite C, Winston-Salem, NC 27103. The head coach Pa ...</p>
                
            </a></div>

            

            <div class="recent-left"><h1>Recent <br> news</h1>
            </div>

        </div>
    
        </section>


        <!---------- Recent news section ------>
    
    </main>
    
</body>


<footer>
    <section class="footer">
        <div class="footer-inner">
                <div class="footer-left">
                    <ul>
                            <li>Sunday : Kids - 17:00-18:00; Seniors - 18:00-21:30</li>
                            <li>Monday : Kids - 16:15-19:00; Seniors - 19:00-21:30</li>
                            <li>Tuesday : Closed.</li>
                            <li>Wednesday : Kids - 17:00-19:00; Seniors - 19:00-21:30 </li>
                            <li>Thursday : Kids - 17:00-18:00; Seniors - 18:00-21:30 </li>
                            <li>Friday : Seniors - 08:30-22:00</li>
                            <li>Saturday: Open Mat - 20:00</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="footer-center">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Store.html">Store</a></li>
                            

                        </ul>
                </div>
            

                <div class="footer-right">
                        <ul>
                            <li>1loboteam@gmail.com</li>
                            <li>086760675</li>
                            <li>Hagdud Ha-Ivri 4, Gan Ha- ir , Floor -1</li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/1loboteam/"><img src="facebook_logolink.png" alt="" height="50px" width="50px" ></a>
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/team_lobo_bjj/"><img src="instagram_logolink.png" alt="" height="50px" width="50px"></a></li>

                        </ul>
                </div>


        </div>        
    </section>


</footer>
</html>
```

```css
a:link{
    color: black;
}

a:visited{
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    color: red;
}



.top-div{
    width: 100%;
    height: 6%;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;


}

.top-div .top-div-left{
    display: block;
    width: 50%;
    color: rgb(182, 182, 182);
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 25px;  
    margin-top: 2px;  
    top: 50px;
}


.top-div .top-div-right{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    

    
}

.top-div .top-div-right .FBNAV{
    margin: 0;
    border:2px solid red;
    
       
}

.nav  {
    display:inline-flex;
   
    background: rgba(170, 3, 3, 0.151);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 650px;
    float: left;
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    
    text-align: center;
    height: 200px;
    
    
    
}

.nav a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul li a {
    margin: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: large;
}

header {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;

    
}

header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    
    
    
    
}

#logo {
    
    align-content: center;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 50px 50px 50px;
}


.social-top ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
}


body{
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}


.welcome-video{
    width: 103%;
    padding-top: 150px;
    
}

#welcome-video-id{
    padding-top: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}


.top-button{
    height: 50px;
    width: 82%;
    color:black;
    background: rgb(182, 182, 182);
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: large;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
}

.welcome-text{
    color:white;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-left: 150px;
    width: 82%;
}

.welcome-programs{
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px 0 15px 0;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 82%;
    text-align: left;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-emphasis: bold;
    float: left;

}


#prog-text{
    margin: 10px 0 20px 5px;

}


.top-section{
    display:block;
    position: relative;
    background: black;
    padding: 50px;
}

.left-wrap{display:block; float:left; width: 33%;}
.left-wrap .left-wrap-inner{
    display: block;
    padding: 50px 350px 50px 100px;

}



.left-wrap .left-wrap-inner .top_left{
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    
    
}

.left-wrap .left-wrap-inner .top-left-text{
    color: rgb(182, 182, 182);
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: rgba(170, 3, 3, 0.151);
    
}

.left-wrap .left-wrap-inner .top-left-text h2{
    padding-top: 20px;
}



.center-wrap{display: block; float: left; width: 33%;}
.center-wrap .center-wrap-inner{
    display: block;
    padding: 50px 350px 50px 100px;
}

.center-wrap .center-wrap-inner .top_center{
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    
}

.center-wrap .center-wrap-inner .top-center-text{
    color: rgb(182, 182, 182);
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: rgba(170, 3, 3, 0.151);
}

.center-wrap .center-wrap-inner .top-center-text h2{
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.right-wrap{display: block; float: left; width: 33%;}
.right-wrap .right-wrap-inner{
    display: block;
    padding: 50px 350px 50px 50px;
}

.right-wrap .right-wrap-inner .top_right {
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.right-wrap .right-wrap-inner .top-right-text{
    color: rgb(182, 182, 182);
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
    background: rgba(170, 3, 3, 0.151);
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.right-wrap .right-wrap-inner .top-right-text h2{
    padding-top: 20px;
}




.mid-sec-header{
    display: inline-block;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 0px 0 15px 0;
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 82%;
    text-align: left;
    background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-emphasis: bold;
    float: left;
}

#coach-info{
    margin: 10px 0 20px 5px;
}
.mid-section{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8%;
    
}

.mid-section .mid-section-inner-left{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 28%;
    

    
}

.mid-section .mid-section-inner-right{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
    background: black;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    margin-right:190px;

}

.mid-section .mid-section-inner-right .text-mid{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


.mid-section .kids-img{
    display: block;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    padding: 0px 350px 50px 90px;
    margin-left: 60px; 
}

.kid-button{
   
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: larger;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    color: rgb(163, 8, 8);
    background: white;
    
}




#adult-testemonial{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 150px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
    background-color: white;

}

#children-testemonial{
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-right: 150px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    width: 600px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    background-color: white;
}


.lower-section-youtube{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);


}
    

.lower-section-youtube .vids .youtube-left {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 40%;
    padding: 50px 0px 0px 150px;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;

}

.lower-section-youtube .vids .youtube-right {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    width: 45%;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    
    
    
}


.recent-posts{
    width: 82%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    margin-left: 160px;
}

.recent-posts .recent-left{
    display: block;
    width: 15%;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    background: rgba(170, 3, 3, 0.151);
    float: left;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


.recent-posts .recent-right{
    display: block;
    float: right;
    background: rgba(170, 3, 3, 0.151);
    width: 84.5%;
    height: 200px;
    

}

.recent-posts .recent-left h1{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin-top: 20px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
    font-size: xx-large;
    color: white;
}

.recent-posts .recent-right a{
    text-decoration: none;
}














footer {
    
    display: inline-block;
    background: rgba(170, 3, 3, 0.151);
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}

footer ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
}

footer a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

footer .footer-inner .footer-left{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    list-style: none;
}

footer .footer-inner .footer-left ul li { 
    padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

footer .footer-inner .footer-center {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    
    
}

footer .footer-inner .footer-center ul li {
    padding: 12px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

footer .footer-inner .footer-right{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33%;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;

}

footer .footer-inner .footer-right ul li {
    padding: 13px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

About page HTML and CSS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="about.css" type="text/css">
    <title>About | Lobo Academy</title>
</head>

    



<body>



    <header>
        <div class="header">
       
        <div class="top-div">
            <div class="top-div-left"> Get a free bjj class NOW 
                                        Call us at 456465464</div>
           
    
                                        
    
        </div>
    
    
        <div>
        <nav><ul class="nav">
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
            <img id="logo" src="logo_header.webp">
            <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="Store.html">Store</a></li>
    
    
        </ul>
    
        </div>    </nav>
    
            
    </header>

    <main>





        <img class="title-img" src="11924.jpg" alt="">

        <div class="OurAcademy">
            
        <h1>About Lobo Academy</h1>
        <h2>Our Academy</h2>
        <p>We are the premiere Brazilian Jiu Jitsu training center in the Charlotte metro area. Head instructor, Lucas Lepri, is among the most decorated jiu jitsu athletes in the entire world, and we are part of the most dominant team in the history of the sport, Alliance.

            Our mission is to bring world-class instruction and passion for jiu jitsu to inspire people to be their best selves. We believe jiu jitsu is more than just a sport, self-defense system, or fitness program; it’s a lifestyle that improves the whole person. The physical, mental, and transcendent benefits of jiu jitsu should be accessible to everyone, from beginner to world-class competitor and any age, sex, or ethnicity.
            
            We will help you achieve your goals, whether it is self defense, weight loss, confidence or to be a world champion. In the process, you will transform your life and become tougher, safer, fitter, and better.</p>
            
          
        <hr>
            
        <h2>Brazilian Jiu Jitsu makes you..</h2>
        <p>
           <strong> TOUGHER: </strong> Mentally and physically, it prepares you to overcome challenges in life and sport. <br>
           <br>

<strong> SAFER: </strong> Widely considered the best self-defense system, it provides confidence in a world with the realities of bullies or attackers. <br>
<br>
 <strong> FITTER:</strong> Building aerobic and anaero­bic conditioning and incinerating calo­ries, you will be exercising more often and with more intensity. Plus, it’s fun, dynamic, and even ad­dictive. <br>
<br>
 <strong> BETTER: </strong>  Its life lessons and character-building qualities not only you a better athlete, but also a better father, employee, wife, leader, and friend. <br>
        </p>
        
<hr>
<h2>About our facilities</h2>
<p>
    We are located in the Galleria Village shopping center on the Southeast corner of Monroe Rd and Sardis Road North (behind McDonalds & Rite-Aid).
<br>
<br>
Our address is:
1636 Sardis Road North, Suite A-170
Charlotte, NC 28270
<br>
<br>
It is a totally renovated space with:
<br>
<ul>
    
    <li>Nearly 4,000 sq feet</li>
    <li>2,000 sq feet of mat space</li>
    <li>Men & Women’s locker rooms with showers</li>
    <li>Free WiFi</li>
    <li>Lounge/ Seating area</li>
</ul>
</p>

<hr>

    <h2>Children Program</h2>

   
    <p>
        
        Learning a martial art, and Brazilian jiu jitsu in particular, is one of the best gifts you­ can provide a child. It provides character development and personal growth that will impact every area of their life, for the rest of their life. It is a fun way for kids to get into fantastic shape, gain confidence, learn respect, improve discipline, and prevent bullying.
        <br>

        <img src="3.9.png" alt="" width="400px" height="400px">
        Our kids program operates in a fun and nurturing environment, where kids flourish and learn important life lessons like:

        <br>
        <ul>
            <li>Through self-discipline, commitment, and perseverance, you can accomplish anything.</li>
            <li>Improving focus and concentration helps you ignore distractions and fully engage in lessons at school, in sport, and at home.</li>
            <li>Patience pays off.</li>
            <li>When you are healthy and fit, you feel better about yourself and are more confident.</li>
        </ul>

        <h2>Bullying</h2>

        <p>
            Our Kids Program will also empower your kids to prevent or discourage bullying without violence. Through appropriate and effective self-defense techniques, we instill the self-esteem and confidence needed to allow kids to defuse confrontations before they escalate, and how to protect and defend themselves in the event they are attacked. Bullying is the #1 social issue and epidemic in schools today, and it has ripple effects throughout our communities.
            <br>
            <ul>
                <li>Every 7 minutes a child is bullied in the US</li>
                <li>Every month, 3 million children miss school due to fear of bullying</li>
                <li>90% of 4th through 8th graders report being victims of bullying</li>
                <li>1 out of 10 students drop out of school due to repeated bullying</li>
                <li>
                    70% of students believe schools respond poorly to bullying and that adult help is infrequent</li>
            </ul>

    
            
          
        </p>

       <a href="Contact.html"> <h2 id="victimchild"><strong>Dont let your child be the victim</strong></h2> </a>
    </p>


        </div>




    </main>
    
</body>




<footer>
    <section class="footer">
        <div class="footer-inner">
                <div class="footer-left">
                    <ul>
                            <li>Sunday : Kids - 17:00-18:00; Seniors - 18:00-21:30</li>
                            <li>Monday : Kids - 16:15-19:00; Seniors - 19:00-21:30</li>
                            <li>Tuesday : Closed.</li>
                            <li>Wednesday : Kids - 17:00-19:00; Seniors - 19:00-21:30 </li>
                            <li>Thursday : Kids - 17:00-18:00; Seniors - 18:00-21:30 </li>
                            <li>Friday : Seniors - 08:30-22:00</li>
                            <li>Saturday: Open Mat - 20:00</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="footer-center">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                            <li><a href="Store.html">Store</a></li>
                            

                        </ul>
                </div>
            

                <div class="footer-right">
                        <ul>
                            <li>1loboteam@gmail.com</li>
                            <li>086760675</li>
                            <li>Hagdud Ha-Ivri 4, Gan Ha- ir , Floor -1</li>
                            <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/1loboteam/"><img src="facebook_logolink.png" alt="" height="50px" width="50px" ></a>
                            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/team_lobo_bjj/"><img src="instagram_logolink.png" alt="" height="50px" width="50px"></a></li>

                        </ul>
                </div>


        </div>        
    </section>


</footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello. I really want to help you, but it's hard to do without your code.

Comment: post your code and mercy upon us.

Comment: Wont let me to add the about page css file, any ideas how I can share with you guys?

Comment: Use the browsers element inspector to check each element and remove it, until you find the one that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="About.html">About</a></li>
        <img id="logo" src="logo_header.webp">
        <li><a href="Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="Store.html">Store</a></li>
      </ul>
   </div>    
</nav>
```

You closed your div before closing the nav tag! try to review your HTML code there might be simple mistakes like this causing the problems.

Comment: Edited and reviewed. Besides that I've found no errors.